# NAV 2016 - Web Services - 401 Unauthorized - Basic Authorization on Ubuntu or Linux Systems

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, dynamics-crm, navision

We have NAVision 2016 set up with two web services; which work fine when called from a browser on a windows operating system; although when I try to reach the same web service from linux / ubuntu, I don't get the htpasswd dialog to enter the credentials, and even if I put the user and pass in the link, I'll still get a 401 unauthorized.

Can someone guide me towards why this works on windows and not from linux? and how can I eventually fix this so I can call it from a script/python?

Comment: Nav uses ntlm authorization. Not basic.

Comment: Which authentication type are you using in NAV? NavUserPassword?

Comment: That was the issue Sergeyol, it was to windows auth, while it should have been otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested, yo need to use ntlm authentication method.

Using the console, i was able to connect using

```
wget --http-user="domain\username" --http-password="password" http://"your_direction":"your_port"/DynamicsNAV/WS/"route_of_your_published_nav_object" --auth-no-challenge
```

This is the case with no HTTPS. Adapt the comand in case you have HTTPS.

In case you are not using console, you need a browser which accepts NTLM. I think chromium support this authentication method.